# Golang Base64 signature verification VS CryptoJS

Tags: go

I am trying to **convert** a *Node.js* script to *Golang*. However, I always get the error `"error: illegal base64 data at input byte 40"` while decoding *Base64*. May someone help me, already debug and read documentation for few hours... Help is needed!

```js
// Node.js exampe (code copied from Facebook Instant game SDK example)
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
var firstpart = signedRequest.split('.')[0];
firstpart = firstpart.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
const signature = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(firstpart).toString(); // <-- fail here
const dataHash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(signedRequest.split('.')[1], '<APP_SECRET>').toString();
var isValid = signature === dataHash;
const json = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(signedRequest.split('.')[1]).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
const data = JSON.parse(json);
```

Code above is the sample code from Facebook, and the following code (below) is written by me.

```golang
    parts := strings.Split(signedRequest, ".")
    firstPart := parts[0]
    replaced := strings.Replace(firstPart, "-", "+", -1)
    replaced = strings.Replace(replaced, "_", "/", -1)

    signatureByte, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(replaced) // <-- ERROR here
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
        return false, err
    }
    signature := string(signatureByte)

    dataHash := createHmacSHA256(parts[1], "<APP_SECRET>") // TODO: not sure, to string or hex string?

    isValid := signature == dataHash
    if isValid {
        return true, nil
    }
```

The Go Playground is at here https://play.golang.org/p/ilSbqamFdV_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, get rid of the `strings.Replace`s and just use `base64.URLEncoding` instead of `StdEncoding`, since the URL alphabet is clearly what your data is in.

Also, standard base64 data is padded, but your data is not padded, so you need the "raw" encoding, i.e. `base64.RawURLEncoding`. This works:

```
firstPart := parts[0]
signatureByte, err := base64.RawURLEncoding.DecodeString(firstPart)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Pj_LLfirU8M

See the [`base64` package docs](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/#pkg-variables) and the [base64 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#page-7) for more info.

Comment: Wow, you save my life... wow... never thought it can be solved so fast... wow, amazing.... thanks